# Visual Studio Team services run webtest

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, vstest.console.exe

I am a bit new to the Team services, So usual apologies first. I am in need of running a webtest (webtest1.webtest created by recording browser steps i.e the same used for load test runs) which runs fine locally on a VS 2015. I am looking for a method to run that on Team services.

To give you an outline i will check in the code on Team service repository and CI starts the build process containing visual studio build and unit tests which runs with a agent deployed locally in my VM. If units tests are successful, it gets deployed to Test environment and then i need the web test to execute here if it goes successfully then it gets deployed to prod.

I read through few posts which outlines running a webtest as load test on Team services but i dont want to do a load test i just like to execute it once as part of scenario/fnctional/integration testing, i.e whether the pages are accessible and all data comes through or something like that.

The webtest runs fine when run with mstest.exe locally in commandline but team services uses vstest.console.exe which dosent execute it. It states that no test cases were found (i tried with both dll and webtest1.webtest as part of build).

I cant get it working on vstest.console.exe locally on commandline as well some suggested orderedtest and few other methods. what i get is missing orderedtestadapter when executed locallys in commandline.

i was thinking about executing the test using mstest.exe in commandline as one of Team service build task but then how to go about loading the trx file back to the build results Also should i be going this or any other better way to go.

Any steps on how to resolve it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to these steps to achieve your requirements:

1. Add Delete files step/task (delete previous test result files if repository isn’t cleaned)
   [image]
2. Add Run Command Line step/task to execute MSTest command
   [image]
3. Add Publish Test Results step/task

[image]

On the other hand, you can do test in Unit Test too, just send the request and check the response, related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095627/unit-testing-http-requests-in-c-sharp).