# Can I Integrate Web Tests (written in visual studio) in Azure Devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, web-testing

I have a web api (REST) project that is written in .NET and I have written a few webtests (.webtest) that test those apis.

While those tests run fine locally from visual studio, I want to integrate them into my VSTS (Azure Devops) build pipeline, so as to identify and breaking changes that could break any of those APIs.

I am not able to find any task in build pipeline which can run the webtests as part of build. I see option for running unit-tests though.

So, wanted to check what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to find an alternative approach as this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops#visual-studio-web-performance-test-webtest-file) implies it has been deprecated.

> Visual Studio web performance test (.webtest file) is tied to the load
>   test functionality and is deprecated. Some customers have used
>   .webtest for other purposes such as running API tests, even though it
>   was not designed for that purpose. Many API testing alternatives are
>   available in the market. [SOAP UI](https://www.soapui.org/) is a free, open source alternative to
>   consider, and is also available as a commercial option with additional
>   capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use cmd task command line to run MSTest with arguments.

1. Add Run Command Line step/task to execute MSTest command
   [image]
2. Add Publish Test Results step/task

[image]

On the other hand, you can do test in Unit Test too, just send the request and check the response, related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095627/unit-testing-http-requests-in-c-sharp).

Also as *Matt* mentioned, since Visual Studio web performance tests (.webtest files) are tied to the load test functionality and is also **deprecated**.  You could take a look at this blog here: [Cloud-based load testing service end of life](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/)